# What would be the best solution to send data between Python and C#?

Tags: c#, python, json

I'm currently working on a C# application that needs to take advantage of the python NLP library, "spaCy", to parse text into data (Dict/JSON) that can be used on C# application

The application currently runs the python script with a unique id as a parameter, python finds the a txt file to parse on the disk using the id as the filename, does it's thing.. (parse into object) then returns the id to the C#.

I'd like to avoid saving to disk if possible.

```
 public string parse(string s)
    {
        process.Arguments = pythonscript + " " + s; //pythonscript = python script name, s = location of txt file to parse
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = process;
        p.Start();
        return ((StreamReader)p.StandardOutput).ReadToEnd().Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, ".json"); //json location
    }
```

Comment: Depending on your platform you can use [some or any of these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Approaches).

Comment: .NET 4 and later should be able to call Python code directly. Look for the [Dynamic Lang Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/dynamic-language-runtime-overview) and IronPython

Comment: @bommelding trying IronPython now, Looks promising. Thank you